# Be sure that an input parameter fulfills multiple type criteria

Tags: java, generics, types

I have two interfaces, A and B. I'm writing a function, and I want it to only take in objects that use both interfaces. This is some of the things I've been trying. I hope my question is clear.

```
    public void function((? implements A,B) thing) {
        // do things
    }

    public <T extends A, T extends B> void function(T thing) {
        // do things
    }

    public <T extends A,B> void function(T thing) {
        // do things
    }
```

None of these attempts worked though. Thanks in advance for any insight into this.

Comment: Did any of them work?

Comment: Nope :(, I'm not sure this is even possible.

Comment: Try creating a 3rd interface that extends from both A & B

Comment: If they did, which type would you be using to call methods on? MadProgrammer's suggestion is the way to go.

Comment: Doh, I don't know why I didn't see that. Thanks guys, I suppose @MadProgrammer, if you type up a short answer, I'll accept it. Thanks guys.

Comment: @InspiredOne Forest, Trees ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating a 3rd interface that extends from `A` & `B` and use that as your method marker...

```
public interface C extends A, B {
}
```

Then you would only need to worry about `C`...

```
public <T extends C> void function(T thing) {
    // do things
}
```

This does mean that anyone calling the method MUST have implement `C` and not just `A` and `B`, but it should get you across the line...

That is...

```
public class MyAB implements A, B {
}
```

Can't be passed to `function`, `MyAB` must implement `C`